# Pyrogram how promote_chat_member to change_info

Tags: python, pyrogram

```
   async with Client("chelebot", api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH) as client:
        for title, desc in zip(channel_titles, channel_descriptions):
            channel = await client.create_channel(title, desc)
            print("Channel created:", channel.title)
            print("Channel ID:", channel.id)
            for user_id in user_ids:
                await client.add_chat_members(channel.id, user_id)
                await client.promote_chat_member(channel.id, user_id, can_invite_users=True,                                       can_delete_messages=True, can_restrict_members=True, can_pin_messages=True, can_promote_members=False)))
                await client.add_chat_members(channel.id, bot_username)
                await client.promote_chat_member(channel.id, bot_username,)
                print(f"User {user_id} invited to channel {channel.title} as admin")
```

This is part of my code. I need get invited user admin status and give the opportunity to change info about channel. But I take this exception:

> TypeError: PromoteChatMember.promote_chat_member() got an unexpected keyword argument 'can_change_info'

How can I fix it, or any other options?

If I use `client.promote_chat_member(channel.id, user_id)` only with mandatory parameters, its work without exceptions. But not like I need.